# Error in running Scala in terminal: "object apache is not a member of package org"

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm using sublime to write my first Scala program, and I'm using terminal to run it.
First I use `scalac assignment2.scala` command to compile it, but it show error message:"error: object apache is not a member of package org"
How can I do to fix it?

This is my code:

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext 
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._

object assignment2 {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("assignment2")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

    val input = sc.parallelize(List(1, 2, 3, 4)) 
    val result = input.map(x => x * x) 
    println(result.collect().mkString(","))
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Where are you trying to submit the job. To run any spark application you need to submit it from **bin/spark-submit** in your spark installation directory or you need to have spark-home set in your environment, which you can refer while submitting.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can't run spark-scala file directly because for compilation your scala class, you need spark library. So for executing scala file you required spark-shell. For executing your spark scala file inside spark-shell, please find the below steps:

1. Open your spark-shell using  next command-
   'spark-shell --master yarn-client'
2. load your file with exact location-
   ':load File_Name_With_Absoulte_path'
3. Run you main method using class name- 'ClassName.main(null)'

Comment: Thank you. I tried your 1 step but the terminal said `/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.4.3/libexec/bin/spark-shell: line 60: /usr/local/spark/bin/spark-submit: No such file or directory`
Is this mean I didn't install its library?

Comment: Hi, Its not a library. It is present inside your spark sandbox. When you download the spark from spark offical website, you will get that in tar file, after extraction of tar file you will get spark sandbox. Then go to bin folder. you will get spark-shell. Refer this link to download latest spark http://spark.apache.org/downloads.html